# Why onClick handler not changing className of icon tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Whenever i am clicking on square icon which have onClick handler linked with it it does not change className of that icon .

Inside the icon tag if box.isChecked === true then i want to show className of "far fa-check-square icon"
but if box.isChecked === false then i want to show className of "far fa-square icon " . But it is not working .

App js file :

```
import React , {useState} from 'react'
const data = [
{
    id:0,
    para:"This is Box One",
    isChecked:false
},
{
    id:1,
    para:"This is Box Two",
    isChecked:false
},
{
    id:2,
    para:"This is Box Three",
    isChecked:false
},
{
    id:3,
    para:"This is Box Four",
    isChecked:false
}];


const App = () => {
let [list,setList] = useState(data);

const checked = (id) => {
    for(let i = 0;i < list.length;i++){
        if(i === id){
            if(list[i].isChecked === false){
                list[i].isChecked = true;
                break;
            }else{
                list[i].isChecked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    let newList = list;
    console.log(newList);
    setList(newList);
}

return(
    <>
        {list.map((box) => {
            return (
                <div className="box" key={box.id}>
                    <i className={box.isChecked === true ? "far fa-check-square icon":"far fa-square icon"} onClick={() => checked(box.id)}> </i>
                    <p className="para"> {box.para} </p>
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </>
)}
export default App;
```

Index js file :

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Index css file :

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box{
width:250px;
padding:15px;
margin:0px 0px 15px 0px;
background-color:rgb(81, 162, 255);
}
.icon{
font-size:25px;
cursor:pointer;
color:white;
margin:0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.para{
font-size:20px;
font-family:arial;
color:white;
}
```

Comment: does the console.log show the change?

Comment: Yes console.log is showing the change , but still className is not changing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code block, you are not changing the reference to the array, just mutating the values. `setState` will not trigger a re-render unless the value reference changes.

```
const checked = (id) => {
    for(let i = 0;i < list.length;i++){
        if(i === id){
            if(list[i].isChecked === false){
                list[i].isChecked = true;
                break;
            }else{
                list[i].isChecked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    let newList = list; // <-- you are not creating a new array here.
    console.log(newList);
    setList(newList);
}
```

To fix this issue, you can clone the array with the updated values.

```
setList([...list]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that React checks for changes in props and state by doing a shallow object equality check. If you set the state to the same initial object/ array, React doesn't do anything to update it.

So you should do this instead

```
let newList = [...list]; 

    setList(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid mutate your state always, your issue is that you are passing the same reference instead of a clone of your array so your state is not updating internally at all.

```
import React , {useState} from 'react'
const data = [
{
    id:0,
    para:"This is Box One",
    isChecked:false
},
{
    id:1,
    para:"This is Box Two",
    isChecked:false
},
{
    id:2,
    para:"This is Box Three",
    isChecked:false
},
{
    id:3,
    para:"This is Box Four",
    isChecked:false
}];


const App = () => {
let [list,setList] = useState(data);

const updateList = (id) => {
    setList((prevList) => {
        return prevList.map((box) => {
           if(box.id === id){
             if(!box.isChecked){
               box.isChecked = true;
             } else {
               box.isChecked = false;
             }
           }
         })
    });
}

return(
    <>
        {list.map((box) => {
            return (
                <div className="box" key={box.id}>
                    <i className={box.isChecked === true ? "far fa-check-square icon":"far fa-square icon"} onClick={() => updateList(box.id)}> </i>
                    <p className="para"> {box.para} </p>
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </>
)}
export default App;
```